# Fancy header and footer with lines aligned with chapter lines corner numbering nightmare

Tags: header-footer, align, page-numbering, fancyhdr, addlines

I am fighting with a very horrible master thesis template. Some smart _ss designed some features which couldn't be done in MS Word without manual correction so I'm trying to make it works in LaTeX to hack it.

I stuck on headers and footers. They should consist a horizontal line aligned with the chapter lines on and text. The header should have the capitalized chapter name. The footer should have a static text: "page" on the first line of text block and odd/even corner numbering on the second page. All with Verdana font.

See attached pictures.

I've tried to mess around with `fandyhdr` but my `LaTeX` skill is not good enough.
Could somebody help me? Thank you.

---

[image: Even footer with odd header]

---

[image: Odd footer with even header]

Here is my template code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc
\usepackage[top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm, inner=3cm, outer=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{80}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


% BARVY
\definecolor{ukred}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{ukgray}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{ukredlight}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{ukgraylight}{RGB}{192,192,192}

% TABULKY A OBRÁZKY
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[font={color=ukgray},figurename=Obr.,tablename=Tab.,labelfont={color=ukgray,bf}]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,singlelinecheck = false}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\rowcolors{1}{ukgraylight}{white}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Obsah}

% NUMBERS AND LINES AT CAPTIONS
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\color{ukred}\lsstyle}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thechapter\enspace\else\thechapter\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}}\thechapter}}\fi}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}
%
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\large}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thesection\enspace\else\thesection\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{#1\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\smash{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}}}\thesection}}\fi}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thesubsection\enspace\else\thesubsection\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{#1\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\smash{\rule[-1.25ex]{\marginparwidth}{0.5ex}}}\thesubsection}}\fi} \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}
%%%%%%%%%

% HEADER

% FOOTER
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{ukgraylight}\hrule height 2.84pt \vspace{0.1cm} \textsf{\small{strana}\\ \vspace{0.15cm} \textbf{\Large{\thepage}}}}

% CITACE
\addbibresource{citace.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Nadpis 1. úrovně}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Nadpis 3. úrovně}

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{První kapitola dizertace}
\lipsum[1]\par
    Tady odcitujeme nějaký zdroj, ať víš, jak se vkládají. K tomu si budeš bohužel muset přečíst : \href{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management}{tento článek:}, ale na druhou stranu, věř mi, že s přibývajícím zdroji se Ti to automatické generování stylu bude hodit. Citace pro \LaTeX Ti totiž umožní kde jaká slušná databáze, takže se Ti to ve výsledku všechno zjednoduší. Takže nějaké citace% \cite{einstein}. Nebo další \cite{dirac}.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=110mm, cfbox = ukgray 1mm 0pt]{Auticko.png}
    \caption{Autíčko s tlustým popiskem bez názvu kapitoly, netlustým textem a pojebkaným rámečkem okolo...\label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
Tady bude zase nějaká tabulka...\par

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Nějaká tabulka}
%       \cfbox ukgray 1mm 0pt{
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r}
        N & R & C &   T \\ \hline % odd -- lightblue (wrong)
        8 & 8 & 4 & 444 \\        % even 
        9 & 8 & 4 & 124 \\        % odd -- lightblue (wrong)
        10 & 8 & 4 & 672 \\        % even 
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum
\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Seznam použitých zkratek a symbolů}
\chapter{Seznam použitých zdrojů}
\printbibliography



\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you loading the `caption` more than once? And why is `hyperref` not the last package to be loaded?

Comment: You can specify the header by using `\fancyhead[LE]{Here is the text you want to see on Left head, Even pages}`. There are also `LO,RE,RO,CE,CO` options

Comment: To use Verdana you can do this: `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\newfontfamily\HEADINGS{Verdana}` in the preamble. To switch to Verdana simply type \HEADINGS where you want to.
`\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\HEADINGS\lsstyle}`

Comment: @MichaelFreimann If the OP uses Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: To make line in headers and footers use `\renewcommand\headrule{some code}` and `\renewcommand\footrule{some code}`. The line itself is produced with `\hrule`. You can specify its width with
`\hrule height 2pt`

Comment: @TeXnician yes, didn't think about it, I always use Lua. I think if you want to use a lot of fonts and switch easily, it's better to use Xe/Lua

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've no idea what you mean with the loading the `caption` more than once. The Verdana font is the last thing which is worring me. The lines and the numbers at corners are problem for me. The font is the last thing to do for me.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann Thanks for advice. I will try to make something but I will probably stuck again on the right indentation of line. The chapter and section code are not from me, I don't have such skill in LaTeX. I think I will go on with MS Word because it will be less afford to do it manually than to learn necessary skill and make it work in LaTeX.

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi I don't clearly understant your problem. What do you mean by indentation of a line? You mean the line below the header, or the line near the chapter title?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I've tried to use your suggestions but it actually doesn't anything at all. My LaTeX template does produce a regular header/footer with a regular page numbering instead of the fancy numbering with lines and the static text according pictures which are posted in my question. My problem is that I don't know how to do it. About the indentation - Probably, the "indentation" isn't a right word. The line should start on inner edge of page aligned with text and it should ends on outer edge of page, aligned with the chapter/section lines, like on the pictures posted in my question.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I've updated my template according your suggestion with `\fancyhead[]` but `twosides` tag in `\documentclass` is ignored and `\fancyhead[]` does just left side numbering instead of odd/even|left/right positioning. :-(

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi about the pagenumbering: the page number appears to be on the outer edge, except for the pages, where you  start a new chapter (it changes style only for the particular page). This happens because Tex applies `\thispagestyle{plain}`, when you start a chapter. It can be easily fixed with overriding the `empty` style by:
`\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{add your code here}
}`

Give me a sec, and I will try smth with the line

Comment: @MichaelFreimann `empty != plain`.

Comment: @cfr oops, that it a mistake. Though, it doesn't affect the functionality)

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi okay, I have found something here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55981/headrule-length-in-fancyhdr
The control is performed by `\setlength\FHleft{1cm} \setlength\FHright{0cm}`. But this doesn't give you an option to make the rules wider than the body depending on the even/odd pages. BUT! You can put it inside the `\fancyhead[the page type]` command, so the command will be redifined every time you go to the next page. You can set different lengths for even and odd pages.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the odd and even pages the right way around? It is most unusual to put the page numbers on the inside, by the binding.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann `fancyhdr` provides specialised commands for this. Better to use those.

Comment: You can also use `\hbox` command and tell it to be `\paperwidth`, so you will get a box with the width of a paper, so you can do whatever you want in it

Comment: @cfr like here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49652/how-do-you-increase-headrule-length-in-fancyhdr ?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann Well, sort of. But see the comments. Adding `\textwidth` is rarely going to be sensible unless you have very wide margins and a very narrow text block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this is one of the worst styles I've seen. Not only does it not conform to standard typographical conventions. It does not even conform to its own. It is horribly inconsistent, lop-sided and distracting.

But if you have to use it, you have to use it. I would hate to try doing this in Word. It isn't much fun even in LaTeX.

- The reason the side rule things are running to the paper's edge is because they use the width of the space allowed for marginal notes, but they are typeset on the opposite side of the text block, which does not allow room for such things. I've hard-coded the inner margin width, but you could pick this up programmatically if you needed to. The width of the rule is stored in `\siderulewidth` and set equal to `30mm` less twice `\marginparsep`, in a vain attempt to keep at least some sense of symmetry.
- `fancyhdr` provides macros for setting offset's for foot and head rules. We then have to compensate by adjusting for the weird placement of the header and footer content.
- We use `etoolbox` to patch `\footrule` and `\headrule` for colour.
- The `titlesec` configuration is altered to use `\siderulewidth` and to eliminate the need for `\dimexpr`, we load `calc`.
- `hyperref` needs to be loaded last.
- For the sake of the example, `demo` is used and the `.bib` altered as I don't have the files specified in the original.

The result is, I think, the desired awkwardness in all its lumbering glory.

[image: lumbering glory]

The code contains some additional explanation in the form of comments

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, demo]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, inner=3cm, outer=3.5cm, headheight=18pt]{geometry}% 18pt is the minimum height required to accommodate the current header
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[font={color=ukgray},figurename=Obr.,tablename=Tab.,labelfont={color=ukgray,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox,calc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}
\SetTracking[no ligatures={f}]{encoding=*}{80}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}% load last unless using cleveref or similar, which must be loaded right after

% BARVY
\definecolor{ukred}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{ukgray}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\colorlet{ukredlight}{ukred!50}% not sure what this should be but presumably not identical to ukred - this makes mixes 50% ukred with 50% white
\definecolor{ukgraylight}{RGB}{192,192,192}

% TABULKY A OBRÁZKY
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,singlelinecheck = false}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\rowcolors{1}{ukgraylight}{white}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Obsah}

% This is the width of the side rules.
\newlength\siderulewidth
% The inner margin is 30mm.
% This subtracts twice the value of \marginparsep, so the side rules will be \marginparsep from the text block and from the edge of the paper.
% \marginparwidth isn't suitable here because we are setting the rules in the inner margin and not the outer one.
\setlength\siderulewidth{30mm-2\marginparsep}

% NUMBERS AND LINES for sectional divisions (NOT captions)

% chapters
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\color{ukred}\lsstyle}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\marginparsep+\siderulewidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thechapter\enspace\else\thechapter\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}}\thechapter}}\fi}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2ex}{1ex}

% sections
\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\large}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\marginparsep+\siderulewidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thesection\enspace\else\thesection\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{#1\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\smash{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}}}\thesection}}\fi}%\titlerule[1.5pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}

% subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries}
{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\llap{\makebox[\marginparsep+\siderulewidth\relax][l]{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}\llap{}}}\thesubsection\enspace\else\thesubsection\enspace \fi}
{0pt}
{#1\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\hfill\rlap{\makebox[\textwidth + \marginparsep][l]{\hspace{\marginparsep}\rlap{\smash{\rule[-1.25ex]{\siderulewidth}{0.5ex}}}\thesubsection}}\fi} \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1ex}{0.5ex}


% FOOTER / HEADER
\fancyhf{}
% NOTE: style is not even consistent!!
\fancyfoot[RE]{% on even pages, the footer is in the inner margin
  \hspace*{\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{\siderulewidth+\marginparsep}%
    \flushleft
    \color{ukgraylight}%
    \sffamily\small strana \\ \vspace{0.15cm} \textbf{\Large\thepage}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\fancyfoot[LO]{% on odd pages, the footer begins at the end of the inner margin
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\siderulewidth+\marginparsep}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \flushleft
    \color{ukgraylight}%
    \sffamily\small strana \\ \vspace{0.15cm} \textbf{\Large\thepage}%
  \end{minipage}%
}
% header always goes on the left, regardless of page, but we need to account for the offset on odd pages
\fancyhf[loh]{\hspace*{\dimexpr\siderulewidth+\marginparsep}\color{ukgraylight}\Large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhf[leh]{\color{ukgraylight}\Large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
% presumably these are meant to be the same
\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{2.84pt}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{2.84pt}
% set the offset for head and foot rules
\fancyheadoffset[ref,lof]{\marginparsep+\siderulewidth}
\makeatletter
% add colours for head and foot rules
\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule\@width}{\color{ukgraylight}\hrule\@width}{\typeout{footrule patched OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Could not patch footrule.}}
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule\@height}{\color{ukredlight}\hrule\@height}{\typeout{headrule patched OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Could not patch headrule.}}
% abolish differences between plain and regular page styles
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
% we don't want numbers in the headers; we don't want section or subsections - just always the chapter name, so mark everything this way
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% p.10 manual
  \markboth{#1}{}}

% CITACE
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Nadpis 1. úrovně}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Nadpis 3. úrovně}

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{První kapitola dizertace}
\lipsum[1]\par
    Tady odcitujeme nějaký zdroj, ať víš, jak se vkládají. K tomu si budeš bohužel muset přečíst : \href{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management}{tento článek:}, ale na druhou stranu, věř mi, že s přibývajícím zdroji se Ti to automatické generování stylu bude hodit. Citace pro \LaTeX Ti totiž umožní kde jaká slušná databáze, takže se Ti to ve výsledku všechno zjednoduší. Takže nějaké citace% \cite{einstein}. Nebo další \cite{dirac}.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=110mm, cfbox = ukgray 1mm 0pt]{Auticko.png}
    \caption{Autíčko s tlustým popiskem bez názvu kapitoly, netlustým textem a pojebkaným rámečkem okolo...\label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
Tady bude zase nějaká tabulka...\par

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Nějaká tabulka}
%       \cfbox ukgray 1mm 0pt{
    \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r}
        N & R & C &   T \\ \hline % odd -- lightblue (wrong)
        8 & 8 & 4 & 444 \\        % even
        9 & 8 & 4 & 124 \\        % odd -- lightblue (wrong)
        10 & 8 & 4 & 672 \\        % even
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum
\section{Nadpis 2. úrovně}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Seznam použitých zkratek a symbolů}
\chapter{Seznam použitých zdrojů}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say it better. I totally agree. I could write you some funny stories about the institute where this template is used but this isn't a right place to do it. And you wouldn't believe me anyway. For example this template design came from the industrial design department of the institute. But anyway... Big thanks for your help!

Comment: I added the `\usepackage{boxhandler}` for the boxed caption aligned with the picture width but the custom `figurename` label has a horizontal offset from other caption text when the caption text is longer than one line. I can't find why. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Mby.png

% Here is an example how to push a boxed picture into the document.
\begin{center}
 \bxfigure[h]{\label{fig:somepic}Popisek obrázku, který může být klidně delší než jeden řádek, ale lze ho zalomit i ručně.}{
 \includegraphics[width=110mm, cfbox = ukgray 1mm 0pt]{auticko.png}
 }
\end{center}

Comment: Captions are quite different from headers and footers. Unless I'm missing something, this is a completely different question. If so, ask a new question with a proper minimal example. It doesn't belong (and cannot be adequately addressed) in comments.

Comment: I've solved the problem with a different `float` package. Thx for reply.

Comment: Nightmare continues... Is there any way how to avoid these type of problems? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElA1r.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwHO.png

Unfortunately, I can't change the chapter titles.

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi One of those links gives me a blank page and the other shows me an exhausted giraffe. If the titles are too long, you need to use the short title option to specify something else for the headers and toc. Since I have no idea what is wrong, this is obviously a wild guess.

Comment: That is strange, I see the original pictures, no blank page no giraffe. Maybe this link will work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1szxy36zcgufzsc/2017-03-01_230959.png?dl=0  and https://www.dropbox.com/s/nue1qls4xfm4fs5/2017-03-01_231013.png?dl=0  If the chapter titles are too long, they are not aligned with text margin. The similar thing happens with headers.

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi I think it was an issue with the site, but I didn't realise that initially. If the titles are too long, use the optional argument. That's what it is for.

Comment: Could you be more specific which argument you means? Are you referring to an argument of `titlesec` ?

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi When you create a chapter or a section or whatever, you have to give one argument and you may give another. The other one is the optional argument. `\section[A Short Title]{An Extremely Long and Very Verbose, Long-Winded and Wordy Title which will Never Ever Fit Properly in Headers and Similar Things}`.

Comment: This a really good solution for a header when I want or I can change  the chapter title to shorter version. But it doesn't solve the problem from the second picture where the chapter title isn't aligned with the text block below the title and the title doesn't respect the page margins. In addition, what to do in situation when I have to have an exactly same text in header according the chapter title even if it means an ugly multiline header (_which is exactly my situation_)?

Comment: @Sto.cosi.cosi `fancyhdr` does not alter the page geometry, which it expects to be constant throughout the document. So, the only thing you could do in that case would be to allow enough room for the longest header you have, which will obviously lead to ugly white space at the top of pages with shorter headers. Put it in a box and align to the baseline. That will keep it within the margins. The title itself going into the page margine looks like an independent issue. *Read the warnings on the console.* Presumably something about bad boxes. Hard to say without code. ***Load `babel`.***

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdqesmx4ycdz0es/UK-cile_dizertace.zip?dl=0 Here is the link for the code. My TeXStudio, or MiKTeX I guess, produce some warnings but I don't know how to tread them.